Salesforce : Set up ROPC OAuth 2.0 for HTTP Callout in flow
I wand to set up a third party app within Salesforce to be able to call out some API from flows.
The authentication protocol is oAuth2 with ROPC flow, meaning that i have to hit only one endpoint URL "token" with multiple fields "client-id", "client-secret", "username", "password".
I'm trying to do it with "legacy named credentials" but I don't know how to set "authorization endpoint URL" in "auth. provider"
Do you know how "not to" authenticate the user (parameters will be store in Salesforce)
Thank you for your help
